# Grub Doesn't Display after installing Xubuntu 12.04

Tags: grub2, xubuntu

I just installed Xubuntu 12.04 alongside Windows XP. I specified my own partitions. However, on boot Grub doesn't seem to appear with the monitor showing "No Signal". After approximately 10 secs (the default wait time on Grub) it boots directly into Xubuntu.

Graphics card is ATi Radeon Xpress 200M.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error could be occurring because of the GRUB resolution exceeding your monitor's resolution.

Try to change the resolution of GRUB (Do this by un-commenting line 25 of the following file):

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

After editing, close the file and type:

```
sudo update-grub
```

If it still does not show up try pressing the Shift when your GRUB is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the grub menu is not good installed.  Try tot repair it with the grub-repair CD.  http://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/  .  Boot with this CD and let repair it automatically.

Comment: I don't think its a problem with the GRUB installation. Its a fresh installation and highly unlikely that GRUB will be corrupt. Besides Xubuntu boots up after default wait time (10s) suggesting that GRUB is indeed working.

Comment: If grub is good installed why do you not see your Windows XP? Just give it a try this boot-repair-cd. You cannot do something wrong when you let repair the program automatically.

Comment: He does'nt just not "see" Windows XP, he does'nt see anything at all and the monitor says no signal. That suggests some kind of video problem rather than problem with GRUB.

Comment: That is possible, but not sure. So if you try first to repair the grub (I do not say that the grub is corrupted - but is possible that is not installed on the wright place - ) - and you have the same result - than you can think at the monitor problem.  You can also try to boot with the shift key down and see what happens then.

Answer (score 0):

Running Boot-Repair with its "out-of-range" option will solve this problem.

Remark: it will do the same as upapilot's command lines, but in GUI mode.