# How to choose a resolution for GRUB2?

Tags: 12.04, gnome, grub2, resolution

I'm using Gnome 3.6.2 with Ubuntu 12.10, my screen resolution is currently 1680x1050, but in GRUB it was something different. First I used /etc/default/grub to uncomment the resolution line and change it to the same resolution I usually use. When that didn't work I downloaded GRUB customizer and changed it there. That didn't work so I ran this:

```
 sudo hwinfo --framebuffer
```

and got this output:

```
Mode 0x0382: 320x200 (+320), 8 bits
Mode 0x030d: 320x200 (+640), 15 bits
Mode 0x030e: 320x200 (+640), 16 bits
Mode 0x030f: 320x200 (+960), 24 bits
Mode 0x0320: 320x200 (+1280), 24 bits
Mode 0x0392: 320x240 (+320), 8 bits
Mode 0x0393: 320x240 (+640), 15 bits
Mode 0x0394: 320x240 (+640), 16 bits
Mode 0x0395: 320x240 (+960), 24 bits
Mode 0x0396: 320x240 (+1280), 24 bits
Mode 0x03a2: 400x300 (+400), 8 bits
Mode 0x03a3: 400x300 (+800), 15 bits
Mode 0x03a4: 400x300 (+800), 16 bits
Mode 0x03a5: 400x300 (+1200), 24 bits
Mode 0x03a6: 400x300 (+1600), 24 bits
Mode 0x03b2: 512x384 (+512), 8 bits
Mode 0x03b3: 512x384 (+1024), 15 bits
Mode 0x03b4: 512x384 (+1024), 16 bits
Mode 0x03b5: 512x384 (+1536), 24 bits
Mode 0x03b6: 512x384 (+2048), 24 bits
Mode 0x03c2: 640x350 (+640), 8 bits
Mode 0x03c3: 640x350 (+1280), 15 bits
Mode 0x03c4: 640x350 (+1280), 16 bits
Mode 0x03c5: 640x350 (+1920), 24 bits
Mode 0x03c6: 640x350 (+2560), 24 bits
Mode 0x0300: 640x400 (+640), 8 bits
Mode 0x0383: 640x400 (+1280), 15 bits
Mode 0x0384: 640x400 (+1280), 16 bits
Mode 0x0385: 640x400 (+1920), 24 bits
Mode 0x0386: 640x400 (+2560), 24 bits
Mode 0x0301: 640x480 (+640), 8 bits
Mode 0x0310: 640x480 (+1280), 15 bits
Mode 0x0311: 640x480 (+1280), 16 bits
Mode 0x0312: 640x480 (+1920), 24 bits
Mode 0x0321: 640x480 (+2560), 24 bits
Mode 0x0303: 800x600 (+800), 8 bits
Mode 0x0313: 800x600 (+1600), 15 bits
Mode 0x0314: 800x600 (+1600), 16 bits
Mode 0x0315: 800x600 (+2400), 24 bits
Mode 0x0322: 800x600 (+3200), 24 bits
Mode 0x0305: 1024x768 (+1024), 8 bits
Mode 0x0316: 1024x768 (+2048), 15 bits
Mode 0x0317: 1024x768 (+2048), 16 bits
Mode 0x0318: 1024x768 (+3072), 24 bits
Mode 0x0307: 1280x1024 (+1280), 8 bits
Mode 0x0319: 1280x1024 (+2560), 15 bits
Mode 0x031a: 1280x1024 (+2560), 16 bits
Mode 0x0340: 1400x1050 (+1400), 8 bits
Mode 0x0341: 1400x1050 (+2800), 15 bits
Mode 0x0342: 1400x1050 (+2800), 16 bits
Mode 0x0343: 1400x1050 (+4200), 24 bits
Mode 0x0344: 1400x1050 (+5600), 24 bits
Mode 0x0372: 1600x1200 (+1600), 8 bits
```

The resolution I have GRUB set to now doesn't appear on that list. Maybe that's why it's resisting my changes? Is this a list of all the resolutions my video card can *handle*, or just a list of resolutions? I tried out a couple of them to see if they looked okay but none of them seem to be anywhere close to the ratio I use now (16:10). The only thing that bothers me is that the words are cut off  <s>and my pretty picture won't show</s>. I'm just looking for a resolution that'll show both boot options.

Comment: Have you tried with [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/151626/62483) or [this one](http://askubuntu.com/a/185514/62483)?

Comment: possible duplicated: http://askubuntu.com/q/54067/62483

Comment: That happens to be the first thing I tried when I searched it, which led me to uncomment the line in etc/default/grub. Sorry I forgot to mention it.

Answer (score 0):

**Grub Customizer** can help you.

Installation of Terminal:

> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install grub-customizer

Run it and see the section **Appearance Settings**.

Comment: The OP has say that he tried with that application and didn't work.

Comment: ^ This is true. Thanks for trying though.